# How do I add Windows to Linux Boot Manager?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, microsoft

Hello AskUbuntu Linux StackExchange Community, I have a question regarding the Linux Boot Manager (GRUB) , the one you get once downloaded ubuntu or linux mint etc. Basically my Laptop came with Windows 8 pre-release and I have been using it however I lost Windows boot manager so I'm just wondering how to add windows 8 to linux boot manager if I can. Thanks for any support!

Answer (score 0):

Open Linux terminal emulator (usually Ctrl+Alt+T), and do this:

```
sudo os-prober

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot now
```

If you want to customize GRUB2, just do

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

sudo grub-customizer
```

Comment: Thank You, Yes I installed the customizer and it's working great, you've answered this question for me haha, Thank you. Now I just have to find a way to fix Windows Boot Manager lol